# Login a webside and trigger a button

Tags: internet-explorer, button, triggers

I have an Prob regarding debug.print 
Although I activated the Window (STR+G) debug.print is not shown. Why want I see the debug Print result? So.. I want to find out which Button I have to trigger by using the VBA Code In my case I have 3 options Search, new Search, go back or Sign In 
For Sign In I found a solution for another web Side Sub TestLogin() Dim... Dim LoginForm As MSHTML.HTMLFormElement .. code LoginForm.submit

In the specific case here the Code is almost the same

Sub Get() Dim... Dim HTML Button AS MSHTML.IHTMLELEMENT ... Code

Set Buttons= HTMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("button") For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons Debug.Print HTMLButton.className, HTMLButton.tagName, HTMLButton.Id, HTMLButton.innerText Next Button

End Sub

In this case the code runs until the line Set Buttons= HTMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("button") and it jumps over to End Sub

Here my Code and the Source Code of the Webside with the Buttons to trigger by VBA

```
Sub Search()
Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLElement  As Object



   Dim UserNameInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
   Dim VornameInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement


   Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
   Set IE = CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")


IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate Tabelle1.Range("B1").Text




Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSSTATE_COMPLETE And IE.Busy
Loop


 Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document




   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))

    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("sur")
    HTMLInput.Value = "HI"


    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("given")
     HTMLInput.Value = "Low"

      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))


     Stop

    Here I tried the Debug.Print .. But it does not work

     For Each HTMLButtons In HTMLDoc
       Debug.Print HTMLButton.className, HTMLButton.tagName, HTMLButton.ID, HTMLButton.innerText
     Next IHTMLButton

   Than I tried This code.. and it also does not work

    Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("btn")
    Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClass("urTxtStd").Value("Suchen")
    HTMLButton.Click

End Sub
```

Here The Source Code from the Webside
I have 3 Buttons

Search
New Search 
Back

[Source Code for Search Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIwNE.png)

```
<table id="btn" onclick="triggerDetailedSearch();" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr style="vertical-align: bottom;"><td class="tl o"><td class="tr o"></tr><tr><td class="bl o">&nbsp;</td><td class="br o"><b class="urTxtStd">Suchen</b></td></tr></tbody></table>

<b class="urTxtStd">Suchen</b>

Source Code (New Search) 
<b class="urTxtStd">Neue Suche</b>

Source Code (Back)
<b class="urTxtStd">Zurück</b>

And for all 3 Buttons

SEARCH

<table id="btn" onclick="triggerDetailedSearch();" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr style="vertical-align: bottom;"><td class="tl o"><td class="tr o"></tr><tr><td class="bl o">&nbsp;</td><td class="br o"><b class="urTxtStd">Suchen</b></td></tr></tbody></table>

New Search
<table id="btn" onclick="resetDetailedSearchForm();" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr style="vertical-align: bottom;"><td class="tl lg"><td class="tr lg"></tr><tr><td class="bl lg">&nbsp;</td><td class="br lg"><b class="urTxtStd">Neue Suche</b></td></tr></tbody></table>

BACK
<table id="btn" onclick="goBack();" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr style="vertical-align: bottom;"><td class="tl lg"><td class="tr lg"></tr><tr><td class="bl lg">&nbsp;</td><td class="br lg"><b class="urTxtStd">Zurück</b></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

What have I missed?
Thx for any help
For You all please stay Healthy! 
Pete

Answer (score 0):

I try to refer to your description and understand that there are three buttons on the web page called **Search**, **New Search**, and **Back**. You want to click these buttons. at present, you are trying to loop through buttons and fetching the values of its attributes.

You said that the below code is not working.

```
 For Each HTMLButtons In HTMLDoc
       Debug.Print HTMLButton.className, HTMLButton.tagName, HTMLButton.ID, HTMLButton.innerText
 Next IHTMLButton
```

I try to check your HTML code and found that the buttons you mentioned are created using **Table** element instead of the actual **HTML button** element. This is the reason that your code is not working.

So I suggest you try to use code below will work for fetching the values of its attributes.

```
     Dim tbl As MSHTML.HTMLTable
     For Each tbl In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")

       Debug.Print tbl.className, tbl.tagName, tbl.ID, tbl.innerText
     Next
```

Output:

[image]

Another thing I noticed that all the tables have the same ID attribute value that is **btn**

I suggest you check the function name mentioned in **onclick** to click a particular button using the VBA code.

Example code:

```
 With IE.document

         For Each e In .getElementsByTagName("table")
            If (e.getAttribute("onclick") = "triggerDetailedSearch();") Then
                e.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next e

    End With
```

Further, you can try to modify the code as per your requirements.

Comment: HI Deepak,I added  Dim tbl As MSHTML.HTMLTable

Comment: HI Deepak,I added  Dim tbl As MSHTML.HTMLTable  and later on Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")  After this I implented With IE.document

        Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("table")
        For Each e In elems
            If (e.getAttribute("onclick") = "triggerDetailedSearch();") Then
                e.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next e

    End With   After running the code I got the error  Sub or Function not defiened What have I missed?

Comment: Maybe you are getting an error because 'elems' object is not defined. I suggest you remove this line ' Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("table") ' and modify the line of  For each to this ' For Each e In .getElementsByTagName("table")'.  If something is unclear then please refer the updated code in my answer. You also no need to declare the tbl or HTMLButtons.

Comment: Hi.. I tried to work it out .. but not a glimpse of chance :-) This is my code so far

Comment: With IE.Document

   For e = 7 To .Count


     For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons.getAttribute("onclick")
          If (HTMLButton.getAttribute("onclick") = "triggerDetailedSearch();") Then
                HTMLButton.Click

                Exit For
            End If
        Next e
  
    End With
    
    End Sub

Comment: Can you please inform us which you got this time and on which line you get an error? It can help to understand the issue as the suggested code is working on our side. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: HI Deepak! No Prob! .. I figured my Prob out. It was my Fault. First I copied and pasted the code in my code. That causes the error No Sub or Function declared. After typing your code in my code I got an error in Line For Each e.... But after declaring "e" as Object the code worked. And! It workes fine until today. So! I have learned a lot! thy for your patience! By now I trie to download the search result from the side  Stay healthy ! Pete

Comment: @Pete, from your last response I can see that your issue is solved now. I suggest you please mark the helpful suggestion as an accepted answer. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.